# What's a "political landscape"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

> What were some of the distinguishing features of the Congresses and political landscapes in the 1965, 1981, 1993, and 2009 time periods?

In what context is the phrase "Political landscapes" used in this sentence?

I know what a landscape means but i am unable to figure out how political landscape is defined here. what i have inferred from the definition is "broad scope of political happenings throughout the country. Such things as party in power, issues being discussed by most people, election process and much more" Is this correct or i am wrong on this?

Comment: I've improved the question, but does [the Oxford Dictionaries definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/landscape#landscape__9) help here? If not, please edit the question to make it clear what you're asking. Because there is a General Reference, the question will probably end up being closed.

Comment: I know what a landscape means but i am unable to figure out how political landscape is defined here. what i have inferred from the definition is "broad scope of political happenings throughout the country. Such things as party in power, issues being discussed by most people, election process and much more"   Is this correct or i am wrong on this?

Comment: "to figure out how *political landscape* is defined here," we have to ask on Politics Q&A, not English Language. Voted to close.

Answer (score 3):

A political landscape actually refers to the current state of things, as well as how they are looking in the future.

While these metaphors are never actually used, you could say that a recession is hard work, climbing up a hill, and then a boom is the exhilaration of riding down the other side in a go cart.

It also references the current support for the varying parties, for example the Conservatives might be on top, and higher on a hill.

It also reminds me of this idiom:

> The lay of the land
>
> -- the arrangement or organization of something other than land *(e.g. politics)*. As soon as I get the lay of the land in my new job, things will go better. The company's corporate structure was complex, so understanding the lay of the land took time.

[thefreedictionary.com](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lay+of+the+land)

I think that the political landscape means the same as the political forecast / outlook and the "lay of the land" when referring to politics.

Comment: Your answer has helped improve the intellectual landscape of this site...